# Find the value of the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+(a-y)^2} \frac{1}{1+y^2} dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Can someone help me with the evaluation of the integral 
\begin{equation*}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+(a-y)^2} \frac{1}{1+y^2} dy?
\end{equation*}

Comment: What is $z$ here?

Comment: $z$ is just a parameter .

Comment: Hint: Partial fractions.

Answer (score 1):

This is a convolution integral, which may be evaluated using the Convolution Theorem: a Fourier Transform of a convolution of two functions is the product of the Fourier Transforms of the functions.  In this case, each function is $f(z) = 1/(z^2+1)$, so their FTs are each $\pi e^{-|k|}$, and thus the integral is the IFT of $(\pi/2) e^{-2 |k|}$, or $ 1/(z^2+4)$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
Find $A,B,C,D$ such that
$$\frac{1}{1+(z-y^2)}\cdot \frac{1}{1+y^2}=\frac{Ay+B}{1+(z-y)^2}+\frac{Cy+D}{1+y^2}.$$